# Moving tableView data to another tableView with separate Entity name

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to use a button to move an entire section of my tableView at once. I want it to move all of the selected rows to another tableView and delete them from the first. The first tableView data is saved in SList the second is SCList. Both Entities have attributes item, qty, desc just the first letters change from sl to sc (i.e. slitem to scitem). The problem I am having is getting the data to change from the SList entity to the SCList entity. How do I get it to remove the data from SList entity and change to SCList and add it to the respective tableView?

Button Code:

```
@IBAction func Move(sender: AnyObject) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! SLTableViewCell
    let passValue = cell.cellLabel!.text
    print(passValue)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToSC", sender: self)
}
```

Segue Code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "editItem" {
        let SListController:SLEdit = segue.destinationViewController as! SLEdit
        SListController.item = selectedItem
    }
    if segue.identifier == "moveToSC" {
        let SCListController:SCart = segue.destinationViewController as! SCart
        SCListController.item = item
    }
```

I commented out the "if segue.identifier == "moveToSC"" code and it segues but doesn't pass any information. All that prints is "Optional("Label")" and nothing passes or deleted.

I'm not sure if any other code is needed. If you need to review any please let me know and i'll edit my code.

I'm trying not to use the didSelectRow method because that changes the row from section 0 to section 1. I would like to use a button to move all at once. Do I even have to mess with the Entities or should it move and change it by itself? I'm pretty lost on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that you need to create an instance of `SCList`, set its attribute values to be the same as the attributes of the `SList` object, and then delete the `SList` object.  I understand from your previous questions that you are using a fetchedResultsController for the first tableView, with two sections; the objects to move are in the section 1:

```
@IBAction func Move(sender: AnyObject) {
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![1] 
    let objectsToMove = sectionInfo.objects as! [SList]
    for item in objectsToMove {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SCList", inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext!) as! SCList
        newItem.scitem = item.slitem
        newItem.scqty = item.slqty
        newItem.scdesc = item.scdesc
        self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(item)            
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToSC", sender: self)
}
```

The longer answer to your question is that copying data from one entity to another like this is not ideal - it suggests you might need to think through your data model some more.  You could, for example, have an additional attribute which reflects which tableView the item should appear in.  You would specify predicates for the fetched results controllers to ensure the table views display only the appropriate items.  "Moving" an item would then be a simple matter of changing the value of the new attribute.

Comment: So, basically it would be better to have one entity (say Lists) and have the 4 attributes under it instead of under each separate. Then set however many more I need as bools for, such as slist, sclist or plist = true/false, depending upon which list I want it to appear in. That just got a little more complicated for me, but it does sound like it would be, and hope it is, easier. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me once again. I have everything changed to one entity (List) with the attributes for each list (such as slist, sclist and plist) all set as bools. They're false in the creation of the item unless they are created on the list I want it on. However, they still display on every list. The sort descriptors are for each list (i.e. slist). How do I say if slist = true then display only slist tableview?

Comment: In the fetchrequest, specify a predicate to filter the results to those you want.  Something like `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"slist == true")`

Comment: @WillZimmer See the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPredicate/predicateWithFormat:) for more information about predicates.